# I'm having trouble processing a dynamic number of inputs in a php form

Tags: javascript, php, html, forms, postgresql

so I've done some research around and I haven't been able to find a solution that quite works (probably due to my lack of experience in php).  What I have is an html table in a form that I can dynamically add rows to with Javascript, so when I submit the form, I want to be able to handle an unknown amount of data.  This is what my form looks like

```
 <form action = "getCreditReport.php" method = "post">
      <tbody>
          <tr id='addr0' data-id="0" class="hidden">
              <td data-name="courseDropdown[]">
                  <select name="courseDropdown[]">
                      <option value = "">Select Course</option>

                          <?php
                              $dbconn = pg_connect("host=localhost dbname=ourDB user=postgres password=*******")
                               or die('Could not connect: ' . pg_last_error());

                               $stat = pg_connection_status($dbconn);
                               if ($stat === PGSQL_CONNECTION_OK) {
                                   echo 'Connection status ok';
                               } else {
                                     echo 'Connection status bad';
                                 }

                               $result = pg_query($dbconn, "SELECT id, title FROM courses");
                while ($row = pg_fetch_row($result)) {
                    echo "<option value=".$row[0].">".$row[1]."</option>";
                }
                pg_close($db);
                header('Content-type: application/json');
                echo json_encode($result);
                ?>

              <td data-name="yearDropdown[]">
                  <select name="yearDropdown[]">
                      <option value = "">Select Year Taken</option>
                      <option value = "2015">2015</option>
                      <option value = "2014">2014</option>
                      <option value = "2013">2013</option>
                      <option value = "2012">2012</option>
                      <option value = "2011">2011</option>
                      <option value = "2010">2010</option>
                      <option value = "2009">2009</option>
                      <option value = "2008">2008</option>
                   </select>
               </td>

               <td data-name="selterm[]">
                   <select name="selterm[]">
                       <option value = "">Select Term</option>
                       <option value = "1">Spring</option>
                       <option value = "2">Fall</option>
                       <option value = "3">Winter</option>
                       <option value = "4">Summer</option>
                   </select>
               </td>
               <td data-name="del">
               <button nam"del0" class='btn btn-danger glyphicon glyphicon-remove row-remove'></button>

                </td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
        <input type= "submit" value = "Submit">
    </form>
```

My function to add rows copies the name of each of the select boxes, and since they are an array, I was hoping that when they got handled that I could just do something like this in getCreditReport.php...

```
<html>
<body>
`<?php

    $dbconn = pg_connect("host=localhost dbname=ourDB user=postgres password=*****") 
    or die('Could not connect: ' . pg_last_error()); 
        // For as many rows as the user submits
        for ($i = 0; $i < count($_POST['courseDropdown']); $i++) {
            $courseDropdown = $_POST['courseDropdown'][$i];  // Get this course from the array

            // Do some PHP Stuff Here, maybe...
            echo $courseDropdown;
        }
        pg_close();

    ?>
</body>
</html>
```

I was hoping that $_POST['courseDropdown'] would be an array of the values from all the selected options in the rows that the user added before submission, but when I try to run this, nothing is echoed.

Again, very inexperienced with PHP so please go easy on me, but what might be going on here?  Is this a good approach to a solution?  If not what might be a better way?  Thanks in advance!

Here is the code to add dynamic rows.

```
<script>    
    function addDynamicRows(table) {
            // Dynamic Rows Code

            // Get max row id and set new id
            var newid = 0;
            $.each(table.find("tr"), function () {
                if (parseInt($(this).data("id")) > newid) {
                    newid = parseInt($(this).data("id"));
                }
            });
            newid++;

            var tr = $("<tr></tr>", {
                id: "addr" + newid,
                "data-id": newid
            });

            // loop through each td and create new elements with name of newid
            $.each(table.find("tbody tr:nth(0) td"), function () {
                var cur_td = $(this);

                var children = cur_td.children();

                // add new td and element if it has a nane
                if ($(this).data("name") != undefined) {
                    var td = $("<td></td>", {
                        "data-name": $(cur_td).data("name")
                    });

                    var c = $(cur_td).find($(children[0]).prop('tagName')).clone().val("");
                    // Here we won't make the name unique because we want each select name to be
                    // part of the same array. e.x courseDropdown[] for each one will push each 
                    // value to an array that will be passed
                    c.attr("name", $(cur_td).data("name"));
                    c.appendTo($(td));
                    td.appendTo($(tr));
                } else {
                    var td = $("<td></td>", {
                        'text': table.find('tr').length
                    }).appendTo($(tr));
                }
            });

            // add the new row
            $(tr).appendTo(table);

            $(tr).find("td button.row-remove").on("click", function () {
                $(this).closest("tr").remove();
            });
        }
    </script>
```

Comment: In getCreditReport.php before your `$dbconn` bit, could do something like:  

`var_dump($_POST); die()`

Comment: What does your function to duplicate rows look like? Have you tried `var_dump($_POST)` to see what's being submitted?

Comment: var_dump($_POST) gives me: array(3) { ["courseDropdown"]=> array(1) { [0]=> string(0) "" } ["yearDropdown"]=> array(1) { [0]=> string(0) "" } ["selterm"]=> array(1) { [0]=> string(0) "" } }......It seems like the values that are selected aren't actually registering (I did select values for all of the options).  I'll update my post to include the code for the add row function.

Comment: OK add a bunch of rows to the table using that function, the view the source or use Inspect Element/Firebug and see what the names are set as on the new `select`s. I have a feeling that the names are not being set.

Comment: I've checked and just double checked. All of the <select>s are named appropriately.

Comment: Some issues with your code: - when you output data, you need to make sure you properly escape or encode it based on context. Here: `echo "<option value=".$row[0].">".$row[1]."</option>";` if `$row[0]` contains `"` or `>` or `&` you'll be in trouble. Likewise if `row[1]` contains '<' or '&'.

Comment: you're in the middle of some HTML page, and suddenly, you write: `header('Content-type: application/json'); echo json_encode($result);` so you end up with a bunch of JSON in the middle of your HTML, and you've changed the `Content-Type` (though that probably gets ignored with an error).

Comment: your code does indeed receive an array for `courseDropdown`, with a single line, but the value is empty (as are the values for the other fields). What does the `<select>` show as options? Which one is selected, if any?